# Calling C code from within Ruby -- How to use the returned pointer?

Tags: c, ruby, windows, winapi

**Problem:**

I'd like to use in my Ruby program an algorithm that is coded in C and exposed through a DLL.

I would like to treat the algorithm as a black box that I can call from within Ruby -- simply pass in the required parameters and use the result.

Ruby (both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3) has the `Win32API` module which seems intended to make it quite easy to interface with dynamic libraries to do exactly what I'm after.

But the problem is that I can't seem to get the Win32API call to send back a string.

**Details:**

The third-party C function is `CodeGen()`.  It take 6 parameters, including a source string, an arbitrary string to serve as encryption key, and, for simplicity, 4 numerical parameters, one signed int, one unsigned long, and two unsigned shorts.  From these, CodeGen() implements a black-box algorithm to return a resulting string.

The C prototype for CodeGen() is:

```
const char *CodeGen(  int encryp_level, 
                     const char *source_str, const char *encryp_key,
                     unsigned long param_a, 
                     unsigned short param_b, unsigned short param_c
                  )
```

Note that both the input strings are constants, i.e. they are supplied to CodeGen() as strings -- so pointers to constant strings

The return value for CodeGen() is also a string, of fixed maximum length, so it will return a pointer.

**My Question:**

How do I go about setting up the call to CodeGen() and getting back the string it is supposed to generate?

**My attempts:**

The code below simply gives me integers as the return value, when I am expecting to obtain a string.

```
require 'Win32API'

codeGen = Win32API.new("encrypt.dll", "CodeGen", "ISSIII", "S")

ret_str = codeGen.Call(3, "foo", "bar", 0, 0, 0)

puts ret_str
```

However, instead of getting a string back, I get back an integer.  **Edit: Could this be a pointer?**

Although I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7, 64-bit edition, I've also tested the above on Windows XP, 32-bits, and using Ruby 1.8.7, so I'm pretty sure it's something to do with my use of the Win32API itself.

Not sure whether the problem is any of these:

- do the integers (3, 0, ...) need to be packed?
- do I need to distinguish between short and long types?
- am I not properly handling the return value?
- if the return value is a pointer, how do I use this in Ruby?
- something else?

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't know why the `Win32API` approach did not work, I've found an easier solution using `FFI` to the problem of calling C functions from within Ruby or interfacing with DLLs.

---

**Solution using `FFI`**

Use `FFI` in Ruby for interfacing with DLLs, as follows:

- (1)  Install `ffi`          *(works with ruby 1.9.3, ymmv with previous versions)*

  `gem install ffi`
- (2)  Create your own Ruby module to wrap the C function

> ```
> require 'ffi'
>
> module CodeGen                   # Ruby wrapper  (your choice)
>   extend FFI::Library
>   ffi_lib 'codegen'              # DLL name  (given)
>   attach_function 
>         :create_code,            # method name  (your choice)
>         :CreateCodeShort3,       # DLL function name (given)
>           [ :int, :string, :string, :uint, :ushort, :ushort], :string  
>                           # specify C param / return value types 
> end
>
> ret_str = CodeGen.create_code(3, "foo", "bar", 0,0,0)
>
> puts ret_str
> ```

- (3) Run.  Result gives a string as desired.

Done!

Comment: I have a similar issue. My returned char* pointer actually points to a UTF-16 text (it's not ASCII text like in your example). I cannot find a way to bring such string into Ruby

Comment: @G_G: See if String#inspect works.  So if your string is called ret_str, try puts ret_str.inspect  That shoud show you whether the C function is bringing the string into Ruby.

Comment: If you built your own dll with something like msbuild, can you just point FFI to the full path of the DLL instead of in this example where we're using `user_32` ?

Comment: @Schneems: should work.  The example above used a custom dll (not user32).  I ran the program in the same directory as the dll, but you should be able to point to a general directory.  Just remember to properly escape the directory separators in the path using "\\".